# Is monoid the category for untyped lambda calculus?

Tags: lambda-calculus, category-theory

If cartesian closed categories are the model for simply typed lambda calculus, then can it be said that a monoid is a categorical model for untyped lambda calculus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[*$C$-monoids*](https://books.google.si/books?id=6PY_emBeGjUC&lpg=PP1&dq=lambek%20scott%20higher-order&pg=PA93#v=onepage&q&f=false) and their variants is what you are looking for. You can find further references and an account of what is what in Martin Hyland's [Towards a Notion of Lambda Monoid](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~martin/Research/Publications/2014/tnlm14.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm new to category theory so pardon me if it sounds silly but is C-monoids the same thing as monoidal category?

Comment: Nope. It's a rather special kind of object in a category whose structure allows you to model $\lambda$-calculus.

Comment: Is there any other reference which talks and explains the monodical category other than the reference you mentioned? I couldn't find one on Internet!!

Comment: $C$-monoids are described in Lambek & Scott's "Introduction to higher-order categorical logic", [section 15](https://books.google.si/books?id=6PY_emBeGjUC&lpg=PP1&dq=lambek%20scott%20higher-order&pg=PA93#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: Following is the only thing I found: Möbius polynomial species, Domenico Senato, A. Venezia, J. Yang. Please let me know if there is a more direct reference to such.